# RSpec: how to test that parameters are correct in includes().where()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, bdd, rspec-rails

I am new in Rspec testing of Ruby on Rails and I have a question concerning controller tests.

Please, suggest me how to test this line:

```
@dreams = Dream.public_dreams.includes(:user).where("users.type_id = ?", 5)
```

In other words, I want to test if correct parameters were set in the controller. It should display all the dreams of a users with `type_id` equal to `5`.
 Can someone, please, help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've indicated that you "want to make sure...displayed dreams [are] only of users who have type_id equal to 5", this would seem to me more like a model spec than a controller spec, and I would probably refactor the code and spec it out to look something like this (assuming you still want to keep your rigid conditions):

First, refactor query into a scope in the model:

```rb
class DreamsController < ApplicationController
  def your_action
    @dreams = Dream.public_dreams_for_type_five_users
  end
end

class Dream < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.public_dreams
    # your code here to access public dreams
  end

  def self.public_dreams_for_type_five_users
    public_dreams.includes(:user).where("users.type_id = ?", 5)
  end
end
```

Next, test the scope in a model spec against some entries in the database that will pass and fail your expectations (the following spec uses [FactoryGirl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) syntax, but you can substitute it out for whatever fixture-substitute library you like):

```rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe Dream do
  describe ".public_dreams_for_type_five_users" do
    let(:type_five_user_public_dreams) { Dream.public_dreams_for_type_five_users }

    context "for users where type_id is 5" do
      let!(:type_five_dream) { create(:dream, user: create(:user, type_id: 5)) }

      it "includes the user's public dreams" do
        expect(type_five_user_public_dreams).to include(type_five_dream)
      end
    end

    context "for users where type_id is not 5" do
      let!(:type_six_dream) { create(:dream, user: create(:user, type_id: 6)) }

      it "does not include the user's public dreams" do
        expect(type_five_user_public_dreams).to_not include(type_six_dream)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

If you wanted, you could then go and further generalise the class method to be something like `Dream.public_dreams_for_users_of_type(id)` and change the specs accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

There are several answers to that:

1. You could test the query itself:
   I would put such a query in a method or scope of your `Dream` model.
   Then go and test the query in a model spec.
2. You could test the assignment:
   On the other hand you can test the correct assignment in a controller spec with `assigns[:dreams]`

Comment: Thanks for tips. Actually, I would like to test if it selects users of correct type: users.type_id, which should equal to 5 and it is done from users.

Comment: don't test functionality of rails.

Comment: i don't understand what you are asking for.

Comment: if you want to make sure that you only get dreams of a user, you should load the user and use the user relations to access the dreams!

Comment: No, no, I want to make sure if displayed dreams only of users who have type_id equal to 5.

Answer (score 0):

`@dreams.select { |dream| dream.user.type_id = 5 }.should eq(@dreams)` ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am getting an error: private method select called for nil:NilClass